# Linear Algebra - Give an example for $3x3$ matrix for these eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm having trouble with this problem :

Give an example for matrix $A$ with these eigenvalues $\lambda_1-1,\lambda_2=1,\lambda_3=0$ while :

$$v_1=(0,1,1)$$
$$v_2=(1,-1,1)$$
$$v_3=(0,1,-1)$$

$v_1,v_2,v_3$ Are eigenvectors of matrix $A$

I don't know how to find matrix $A$ that apply these terms.

The only thing I came up with is that : 
$$A(\lambda_i)=\lambda_i v_i \rightarrow A(\lambda_i)-\lambda_iv_i =0$$

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $A$ is diagonalizable since $A$ is $3\times 3$ and has three eigenvalues. Hence
$$
A=P\Lambda P^{-1}
$$
where
\begin{align*}
P&=
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1  & 0 \\
1 & -1 & 1 \\
1 & 1  & -1
\end{bmatrix}
&
\Lambda &=
\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 \\
0  & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}